# Remove row with specific value

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
library(data.table)
sales <- data.table(Customer = c(192,964,929,345,898,477,705,804,188,231,780,611,420,816,171,212,504,526,471,979,524,410,557,152,417,359,435,820,305,268,763,194,757,475,351,933,805,687,813,880,798,327,602,710,785,840,446,891,165,662),
                    Producttype = c(1,2,3,2,3,3,2,1,3,3,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,3,3,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,3,2,1,2,3,1),
                    Price = c(469,721,856,956,554,188,429,502,507,669,427,582,574,992,418,835,652,983,149,917,370,617,876,337,663,252,599,949,915,556,313,842,892,724,415,307,900,114,439,456,541,261,881,757,199,308,958,374,409,738),
                    Quarter = c(2,3,3,4,4,1,4,4,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,3,4,4,1,1,4,1,1,3,2,1,3,3,2,2,2,1,4,3,3,1,1,1,3,1,1))
```

How can I remove (let's say) the row in which Customer = 891?

And then I have another question:

If I want to manipulate the data I use data [row, column]. But when I want to use only the rows in which Quarter equals (for example) 4. I use data [Quarter = 4,] Why is it not data [, Quarter = 4] since Quarter is a column and not a row?

I did not find an appropriate answer in the internet which really explains the why.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to R! `data[Quarter=4,]` is wrong, perhaps you mean `data[Quarter==4,]`? Getting past that, indexing before the comma needs to be on the scale of the number of rows, and `Quarter==4` returns a `logical` vector the same length as `nrow(data)`; if you have `data[, Quarter==4]`, then that might return the same length vector, but there are likely to be not that many columns, which is what the second arg (after the comma) is meant to be used for.

Answer (score 0):

You have used 'data.table' function to import your data, so you could write :

```
 sales[Customer != 891,]
```

The **data[Quarter = 4, ]**, ensures that all columns should be returned for the rows where Quarter is equal to 4. The comma(,) is necessary to only select the rows, and not the column Quarter = 4.

Answer (score 0):

When you use indexing, ie, `data[row, column]` you are telling R to look for either a specific row or column index.

1. **Row**: `sales[sales$Customer %in% c(192,964),]` translates to "search the specific column `Customer` in the data frame (or table) for any rows that have values that contain 192 or 964 and isolate them. Note that data.table will allow for `sales[Customer %in% c(192, 964),]` but data frames cant (use `sales[sales$Customer %in% c(192,964),]`)

```
   Customer Producttype Price Quarter
1:      192           1   469       2
2:      964           2   721       3
```

2. **Columns** `sales[, "Customer"]` translates to "search the data frame (or table) for columns named "Customer" and isolate all its rows

```
    Customer
 1:      192
 2:      964
 3:      929
 4:      345
 5:      898
...
```

Note this returns a data table with one column. If you use  `sales[,Customer]` (data table) or `sales$Customer` (data frame), it will return a vector:

```
# [1] 192 964 929 345 898 477 705 804 188 231 780 611 420 816 171 212 504 526 471 979 524
# [22] 410 557 152 417 359 435 820 305 268 763 194 757 475 351 933 805 687 813 880 798 327
# [43] 602 710 785 840 446 891 165 662
```

You can of course combine - if you did, `sales[sales$Quarter %in% 1:2, c("Customer", "Producttype")]` you would isolate all values of `Customer` and `Producttype` which were in quarters 1 and 2:

```
    Customer Producttype
 1:      192           1
 2:      477           3
 3:      780           1
 4:      611           1
 5:      420           2
...
```